# Can I test an iPhone app on a device synced with another computer?

Tags: iphone, synchronization, iphone-developer-program

Is it possible to test an iPhone app on an iPhone/iPod touch which is synced to a computer *other than the host computer*?

If so, will this also work for testing a device which is synced to a Windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** I tried it yesterday and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You do need to register the device to do any testing at all though. [Here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices) is a good tutorial for how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the link to the tutorial, that's really helpful. Have you tested a device on a non-synced computer before? I just want to find out if anyone else has done it successfully, in case it has any adverse effect on the iPod Touch I've borrowed!

Comment: This is how I install stuff on my wife's phone without going through the hassle of creating an *ad hoc* distribution. It works just fine, just make sure iTunes doesn't sync.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can.  With XCode 3.2.3 it's pretty easy now--you can dynamically load the provisioning certificate to the phone.  To do this, plug in the phone that you want to use via USB, open the Organizer in XCode, and follow the instructions for provisioning the device.  You must be connected to the internet.

Note: if there are new developers agreements from Apple that you haven't accepted yet, this certificate provisioning step may fail silently.